# PHP conditional multi-dimensional value comparison

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i need help with comparing a value that is going to be assigned into a multidimensional array with several value of that comes with last assigned value.

first the arrays are like this:

```
$schedule = array(
    0 => array(//day
        0 => array(//session 1
                0 => array( //room 405
                    0 => "5" //id from arr2 
                ),
                1 => array( //room 406
                    0 => "7"  
                ), 
                2 => array( //room 407
                    0 => ""   
                ),
                3 => array( //room 408
                    0 => ""  
                ) 
        )
)

$idAndNeighbour = array(
     0 => array(
         'id'=>5,
         'neighbour1' => 4,
         'neighbour5' => 22,     
     ),
     1 => array(
         'id'=>7,
         'neighbour1' => 9,
         'neighbour5' => 24,     
     ),
     2 => array(
         'id'=>9,
         'neighbour1' => 7,
         'neighbour5' => 23,     
     ),
     3 => array(
         'id'=>14,
         'neighbour1' => 8,
         'neighbour5' => 26,     
     )
)
```

the next id to be assigned to $schedule is 9, so i need to get the last assigned id, see which id in $idAndNeighbour matches the last assigned id, and compare the id 9 with the last assigned id's neighbour, if 9 matches any of the last assigned id's neighbour then skip 9 and then the next id to be assigned is 14.

how do i solve this?

note: i should not do the comparing just within the $idAndNeighbour because it will continually skip id 9 and other id that matches the neighbour value

Comment: a more detailed example for what i look for: imgur.com/a/eJPPyCS

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to find if 9 is in your leaf nodes, you want [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Here is an example with your data:

```
$schedule = array(
    0 => array(//day
        0 => array(//session 1
                0 => array( //room 405
                    0 => "5" //id from arr2 
                ),
                1 => array( //room 406
                    0 => "7"  
                ), 
                2 => array( //room 407
                    0 => ""   
                ),
                3 => array( //room 408
                    0 => ""  
                ) 
        )
    )
);

$allids = array();

array_walk_recursive($schedule, function ($value, $key) use (&$allids) {
                                    if ($value) $allids[] = $value;
                                });
var_export($allids);

if (array_search(9, $allids) === false) {
    echo "\nIt's not there.\n";
} else echo "\nIt's there.\n";
```

This yields:

```
array (
  0 => '5',
  1 => '7',
)
It's not there.
```

Comment: its not quite what i look for, here's a more detailed example for what i look for: https://imgur.com/a/eJPPyCS

Comment: I think its still at least part what you want, you just have to do a bit more with it.  If I get some time tonight, I'll give you a better example.  In the meantime - are you trying to avoid adding nine to ANY room adjacent in the same session, or specifically the last?  So can you add room 9 even if its a neighbor of 5?

Comment: maybe you are right, yes i am trying to avoid adding nine to any room adjacent in the same session, for the question why its because those id are combination of lecturer and course so if its a neighbour that means there's a lecturer that lectures both of that id, and because one lecturer cant be in two room at one time it shouldnt appear on the same session